# htmlcollection - how do you get elements by id?

Tags: javascript, htmlcollection

I have the following code however it does not work:

```js
let dummyDOM = document.createElement( 'html' );
dummyDOM.innerHTML = text;
const html = dummyDOM.getElementById("someID");
```

I receive: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: dummyDOM.getElementById is not a function`

I know how to get elements by class name but I have not seen a way to get elements by ID. Is this possible with htmlcollection?

Comment: Aren't you already doing it with `getElementById`...?

Comment: Sorry - clarified why it doesn't work

Comment: Ids are supposed to be unique

Comment: Oh, that clears things up a bit. `html` doesn't have a `getElementById` method. Use `document.getElementById("someID");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under [usage notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById#usage_notes) from MDN:

> Unlike some other element-lookup methods such as Document.querySelector() and Document.querySelectorAll(), getElementById() is only available as a method of the global document object, and not available as a method on all element objects in the DOM. Because ID values must be unique throughout the entire document, there is no need for "local" versions of the function.

That means a regular element doesn't have this method. However, regular elements still have a `querySelector` method, that gets the first element found that matches a **CSS selector**.

```js
const html = dummyDOM.querySelector("#someID");
```

Or, if you are planning to add `dummyDOM` to the page, you could just use the original `getElementById`:

```js
const html = document.getElementById("someID");
```

But what you really need is a proper Document, which you can do with [`createDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createDocument):

```js
let dummyDOM = document.implementation.createDocument();
```

Comment: I'm appending some of the HTML to an existing document - what is the benefit of using createDocument here instead?

Comment: @GrantCurell In that case, you should be using the second option listed - where you are eventually going to add `dummyDOM` (and its children) to the page.

Comment: hmmmm if I understand correctly, I don't think I can. I have a large string of HTML I'm getting from elsewhere and then I'm assigning that with innerhtml. Once it has been converted to the htmlcollection, I want to grab a subset of it and return that. If that's the case I wouldn't be able to start with document.getElementById right? Because that's going to only search what is already loaded in the browser?

Comment: @GrantCurell I believe that is the case, so that is why I suggested the two other methods.

Comment: Haven't figured out why yet but getElementByClass works - surprisingly, I've picked a few IDs but querySelector returns nothing - including an element I tested with getElementByClass. Tried it with an id and it returns empty. Investigating now - no errors in the console but I know for sure these IDs exist

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an element by its ID, you can use the `getElementById()` method that you are already using.

For example:

```js
function changeCol(c = "cyan") {
  document.getElementById("id1").style.backgroundColor = c;
}
```

```css
p {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<p id="id1">ID 1</p>
<p>Not ID 1</p>

<button onclick="changeCol('magenta');">Change background</button>
```

You can learn more about `getElementById()` at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

https://devdocs.io/dom/document/getelementbyid

Comment: Apologies, clarified what I'm seeing when I run it in the OP